# Combine two lists of different lengths in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, merge

I have 2 lists of different length.
A gift is selected and assigned to a name, then the next gift will be given to the next name, and so on, in the circle, until the gifts are finished.

```
gifts = ['pencil', 'pen', 'book', 'notebook', 'pencil_box', 'schoolbag', 'stick']
name = ['John', 'Marcus', 'Marie']
```

Expected Output:

```
John: pencil notebook stick
Marcus: pen pencil_box 
Marie: book schoolbag
```

Another example:

```
gifts  = ['car', 'house', 'phone']
name = ['RichieRich']
```

Expected Output:

```
RichieRich: car house phone
```

Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import defaultdict

gifts = ['pencil', 'pen', 'book', 'notebook', 'pencil_box', 'schoolbag', 'stick']
names = ['John', 'Marcus', 'Marie']

gifts_by_name = defaultdict(list)
for name, gift in zip(cycle(names), gifts):
    gifts_by_name[name].append(gift)

for name in names:
    print '%s: %s' % (name, " ".join(gifts_by_name[name]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using for loops:

```py
count = 0 
kids = [yourkids]
gifts = [yourgifts]
outputKids = kids
for gift in gifts:
    if count > kids.length:
        count = 0;
    outputKids[count].push(gift)
    count = count + 1
```

Then just map your "kids' array to your "outputKids" (index-wise) and you have the gifts for each kid.

Comment: My apologies, I did it in javascript :P